# pandas, trying to only sample 5 rows per movie_id, from a dataframe where there are too many rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe df in terms of the total rows
In fact it has too many rows inside of it. And I need to limit the rows amount in a sensible way while still maintaining that each of the movies will have same amount of reviews in the dataframe (currently it varies greatly)

dataframe has shape such as this

first  column is userID, second column is animeID (movieID essentially) third column is just that user's own movie rating of that movie. Each row is a movie review. There should be about 300 movieIDs in the column animeID.

What I need to do in pandas is to limit the amount of rows such that I resample that dataframe to have only something like 5 rows per animeID(i.e. the movieID) and that the new dataframe should only have those newly sampled rows. I got totally stuck on how to do this in pandas I could maybe have done it in excel somewhat easily, but I don't want to separate all my preprocessing into excel stages and pandas stages...

I'm pretty sure that each animeID should have at least 1000 rows (each row is an individual movie review, but it could have been by the same user or a different user). I just need to limit the amount of rows(movie reviews) so that all movies still have reviews about them, but I'm still able to process the data.

I will have about 300 movies (300 animeIDs ) from which I know that those movies will have had at least 1000 reviews about each of them, and I will have already done that. So the main problem is that some of the movies just have huge amount of reviews about them like tens of thousands or something.

[ratingsDataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRvUh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot think of any single function applicable to your case. Instead, you may try following lines where df is the original data frame that you want to sample from:

```
current_row=0
df_sample=pd.DataFrame([],columns=df.columns)
for i in np.unique(df['animeID']):
      new_sample=df[df['animeID']==i].sample(n=5)
      df_sample=pd.concat([df_sample,new_sample],axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the Dataframe into a Numpy array. The problem will reduce to just playing around with arrays. The code for converting the Dataframe into an array is:

```
<numpy_array_name> = <dataframe_name>.values
```

Hope this helps you. If you still want to work with the dataframes, the check out this [article](https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/).